# How to test scala classes for kryo deserialization incompatibility

Tags: scala, versioning, compatibility, kryo

I want to use kryo to serialize and deserialize a hierarchy of classes, like this:

```
case class Apple(bananas: Map[String, Banana], color: Option[String])
case class Banana(cherries: Seq[Cherry], countryOfOrigin: String)
case class Cherry(name: Option[String], age: Int, isTomato: Boolean)
```

Sometimes I want to add and remove fields somewhere in this hierarchy, e.g. to `Cherry`.

I would like to write a unit test which looks at the type hierarchy starting at `Apple` and concludes that data previously serialized with kryo will not deserialize properly—i.e. the deserialized object would not be `==` to the serialized object, if I could have both in memory simultaneously.

In that case, I can update a namespace key in my Redis cache, forget all the old data and rebuild it from scratch. I just need an automated reminder so that I'll remember to do this when I need to.

Some false positives are acceptable; false negatives are not. I'm happy to hardcode something like a serial version UID into my test case and update it whenever I change the underlying class hierarchy. It's acceptable if the test only works on DAG-shaped hierarchies, but handling cycles is definitely welcome.

Is there some way of computing the bit I want by using e.g. the `TypeTag` machinery to walk a description of the type hierarchy? Exactly which aspects of source type declaration does kryo compatibility depend on, and how do I plop out a representation of those features using e.g. `TypeTag`?

I use `io.altoo.akka.serialization.kryo.KryoSerializer` to (de)serialize, see https://github.com/altoo-ag/akka-kryo-serialization.

Answer (score 1):

One trick I've used in this area is to check in samples (ScalaCheck and its generators may prove useful here) of data serialized with "important" versions of the old serialization.  Then you write tests that literally check that the new serialization properly deserializes.

You may run into a developer under pressure to get a change in who makes the deserialization test green by changing the serialized data (this happened to me).  You can address that by checking in the checksums of the serialized test data and validating them at the start of CI: changing those checksums should be pretty apparent in review that something questionable is going on.

I suspect that this approach will have a somewhat better return-on-effort than the alternative of reimplementing a portion of kryo's type system and figuring out a way to serialize a representation of that type system for comparison against future versions of the code.

Comment: Do you have an easy way of producing data literals? If I just `println` the generated instances Scala "helpfully" omits the double quotes around strings. Workarounds abound: map a `Gen[Apple]` into a `Gen[(serialization output, theApple.hashCode)]`, write samples of that into my test case and then compare for hash equality, but it's less precise. Or I can generate two different serializations, e.g. kryo vs. play-json, deserialize twice and test for equality, but that really wants independent (preferably disjoint) deserialization failure modes. Ideas?

Comment: I would probably, after saving the serialized test cases, write the spec along the lines of `"deserializing old data" should "produce valid Apples"` (to use the ScalaTest spec style)... what valid means in that case is going to be domain specific: in some contexts, getting an `Apple` is sufficient, in others you'd be validating that the essential domain constraints are still adhered to, or that some more essential field is propagated.